# How to clear TinyMCE draft after submitting?

Tags: caching, tinymce, autosave

I'm using TinyMCE with great results, the only problem now is that using the autosave plugin and after submitting a form, when I try to create a new record the draft for the last submitted form gets loaded.
I've spent some hours looking for a solution without success so, if anyone knows how can I clear the draft after submitting (or onSubmit, or something) I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would the following help?

```
<script>
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // clear tinymce contents
  tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After the form has been submitted and you can clean up, e.g. empty the content are, also clear the `localStorage` by key:

```
// https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/autosave/#autosave_prefix
localStorage.removeItem(
  `tinymce-autosave-${window.location.pathname}${window.location.hash}${window.location.search}-comment-editor-draft`
);
```